# A new knife for Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, rosh-hashanah-new-year, symbols-symbology

There is a custom to buy a knife for Rosh Hashanah: the qualifier is that the knife not be serrated. What is the source for this custom and what is the significance of the knife not having edges?

Comment: [Related??](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1747)

Comment: It seems to be counter not related

Comment: @msh210: nitei gavriel touches on this in the footnotes here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&pgnum=154 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&pgnum=155

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/561075/jewish/Purchasing-a-New-Knife-for-Rosh-Hashanah.htm

> "Chatach," (חתך), which means "cut," is the name of the angel in
>   charge of livelihood.
>
> Consider that the final letters of the Hebrew words, פותח את ידך, "You
>   open up Your hand" (Psalms 145:16), spell "chatach." Additionally, the
>   word that follows in the verse, "u'masbe'a" – "and satisfy [the desire
>   of every living being]" has the numerical value of 428 – the same
>   value as the word "chatach."
>
> For this reason, purchasing a new, sharp knife is a segulah
>   (spiritually propitious), for livelihood, which we petition from G‑d
>   for the upcoming year.
>
> Nitei Gavriel 11:10

Comment: This appears to be the Nitei Gavriel (Rosh Hashana 19:6). I didn't see anything about the angel named Chatach there: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&pgnum=154

Comment: Look at footnote 8.

Comment: This part "‫נגד השם הפרנסה המרומז בס״ת של‬
‫פותח את ידיך‬
"?

Comment: Yes you got it!